# "Web posting has been disabled for this member by their domain administrator"

Tags: google-groups

I am a manager in a Google group. A friend of mine has registered to the group. When I look at his name in the members' list, I see:

> Web posting has been disabled for this member by their domain administrator.

The friend's email address is "username@orange.net.il". So, initially I thought that the company "orange.net.il" blocked that user from google-groups for some reason. So I called them, but they told me that they don't block users.

So now I am wondering, what is the meaning of this error message and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message means that Google Groups is not turned on for your friend.

From https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/rJBQjCEP3CE by David Bencic

> I have found the issue.  In the domain that is hosted by Google they
>   need to have Google Groups enabled, even if Groups for Business are
>   enabled.   In the Google hosted domain that belongs to the user that
>   is showing this status "Web posting has been disabled for this member
>   by their domain administrator" the admin will need to follow these
>   stpes.
>
> - Open the Admin console for the domain https://admin.google.com/
> - Click on Additional Google Services
> - Click on Google Groups
> - In the top right corner of the gray box you will see three dots, click on this and choose ON for everyone   This will change the state
>     in the impacted group right away.

Comment: Which admin should follow these steps? Is this me (the admin of the group), or the admin of "orange.net.il"?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi The admin of orange.net.il.

Comment: They say that they were hosting their email services at Google several months ago, but then moved to a new email host. Is it possible that Google remembers them and does not allow them to post?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi yes, it's possible. Maybe they changed their email hosting but they didn't delete the user accounts from the directory of Google Apps for their domain. It's worth to say that Google is retiring Google Apps for ISP so the accounts could be deleted automatically someday, perhaps before the end of this year.

Comment: 5 years later, this is still the correct answer. Thanks @Rubén!